# How to change Grive folder location?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, grive

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to know how to change Grive's default folder location?

So far I know that when I create grive via terminal you can tell it which folder with the following instruction :

```
cd /your-folder/grive -a
```

But what I don't know is how to setup grive's interface with this exact folder location.

Any help will be greatly appresiated.

Answer (score 0):

If you type 'grive -h' it will show some help.

The command you want is: `grive -p /your-folder/grive -a`

Answer (score 0):

After you have set up your sync with grive-tools, just copy your Goolge Folder to the new desired location and then edit the grive indicator as follows:

```
sudo nano /opt/grive-tools/grive-indicator
```

Scroll all the way down until you find the "# Main Env Vars" section and change the googleDriveFolder path. The default is:

```
googleDriveFolder = os.path.join(userHome,googleDrive)
```

If you want to put the Google Drive folder under the Public folder you can do this:

```
googleDriveFolder = os.path.join(userHome,'Public',googleDrive)
```

You may also just use an absolute path like this:

```
googleDriveFolder ='/usr/share/locale'
```

For more information on how to use the os.path.join function, read here:https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Answer (score -1):

I got an answer:

Instead of using grive I used Insync.

There you can change easily the directory for the sync folder, sync more than one accounts and in my humble opinion its a better service.

PS: It also works for linux.

More info at:
www.insynchq.com

Thanks,